# React: How to prompt for unsaved changes when navigating with react-router-component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-router-component

Redux state holds flag for unsaved changes, and I want to prompt user when navigating (clicks a Link) if this flag is set. I'm using [react-router-component](https://github.com/STRML/react-router-component). I didn't find how to do this in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply be able to create your own Link component (that inherits from `Router.NavigatableMixin`, example here https://github.com/STRML/react-router-component/issues/105#issuecomment-63874805 and here  http://strml.viewdocs.io/react-router-component/recipes/custom-link/).

Then you just handle click event on that component by prompting user if they want to navigate away if 'yes' you just continue with `this.navigate(...)` (from within your component, inheriting from Navigatable).

Comment: It worked otherwise, but the mouse pointer hover state disappeared. How do I preserve the original behavior of Link other than writing custom click handler?

Comment: Hover state is probably css-only thing - check styles on Link component & compare with yours.

Comment: This looks like a very bad solution because there are potentially a lot of ways that you could navigate away without clicking the link. e..g. hitting "back" in your browser.

Answer (score 13):

Anyone reaching this post in 2018 and using the react router 4+, I'd suggest reading this [reacttraining example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions)

TL;DR use the `Prompt` component at the top

```
<Prompt
    when={hasUnsavedChanges}
    message="There are unsaved changes, do you wish to discard them?"
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain how this actually works, or include a more complete code example in your answer?